# Connecting in R with dbConnect and odbc fails, but connecting with RODBC works fine. Why?

Tags: r, database, odbc, exasolution

I am trying to connect to an EXASol database through odbc using R. After setting up the DSN, I can connect to the database using the RODBC package.

```
odbc_channel <- odbcConnect("exa", uid = "username",
                        pwd = "password")
```

This works fine. However, when I try to use dbConnect, the same DSN fails.

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), 
             dsn = "exa", 
             uid = "username",
             pwd = "password")
```

The code begins running and never stops. Any idea what is happening? The DSN seems to be set up correctly since it works with RODBC.

Comment: Long running code does not mean it fails. Possibly the *EXASol* maintains many system/meta tables to be included in connections tab of RStudio. Try `options(connectionObserver = NULL)` at top of script to avoid.

Comment: Perfect that was it thanks